# How to get total and avg in a row of mySQL query

Tags: mysql

I have fetching following data through query

```
select ord_date,sum(product_sales) product_sales from salestable group by ord_date
```

[image]

How can I the following data through query. I am using mySQL 5.7 version

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use aggregate window functions with no partition by clause. Check below for the code.

```
SELECT 
    ord_date, 
    product_sales,
    SUM(product_sales) OVER() as total_sales,
    ROUND(AVG(product_sales) OVER(),2) as avg_sales
FROM Orders;

Result_Set:

[Result_01][1]
```

Comment: I am using mySQL 5.7 version

Comment: @Ashish hello, I use the latest version 8.0.28. I am not sure these capabilities are fully supported in your version.